# declaring shell variable from awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to set a variable in shell to true depending on if certain requirement is met. That requirement is determined by `awk`.

So here's what I do

```
$  different=false

$  awk 'if (certain requirements met) {'different=true'}' inputfile

$  if $different; then
     print "Different
```

However, different does not set to `true`.

PS my `certain requirements met` is definitely true.

Thank you

Comment: You may possible use `awk` for all the test, no need for the extra `if` test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` cannot set variables in the shell that called it. You can use `exit` to set `awk`'s exit status:

```
$ if awk 'if (certain requirements met) {exit 0} else { exit 1 }' inputfile; then
>  printf "different\n"
> fi
```

Or capture the output of `awk` in a variable:

```
$ different=$( awk 'if (certain requirements met) { print "true" } else { print "false" }' inputfile )
$ if [[ $different = true ]]; then
>  printf "different\n"
> else
>  printf "Not different"
> fi
```

Comment: awk cannot set shell variables in the parent shell. But, I believe awk can set values on variables exported to a child shell.

Comment: Thank you. How can I exit `awk` though? For example if a certain requirement is met, exit `awk`, meaning ignore the rest of `awk` code. I do NOT want it to exit the shell code. Just ignore the rest of `awk` and continue the rest of the code...

Comment: `awk` has its own `exit` command, which just exits the `awk` process, not the shell that calls `awk`.

Comment: So I'd just write `exit` in `awk`?

Comment: Yes, just as I wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it.

```
different=$(awk 'if (certain requirements met) {print "true"}' infile)
```

Comment: `else print "false"`?